# Perform HTTPS-Request using Preprocessor in JMeter

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-4.0

I have HTTPS GET request to be executed using a preprocessor before my actual HTTP sampler

Is there anyway to hit an api(https) using Preprocessor ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 PreProccessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), just create a URL with your site as:

```
new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection()
```

Comment: I am getting following errors 
1. 'javax.script.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target'

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager

class TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null;  }
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
}
def context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance('SSL') // or maybe `TLS` depending on your endpoint configuration
context.init(null, (TrustManager[]) [new TrustManager()], new java.security.SecureRandom())
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory())

log.info('https://your URL here /'.toURL().text)
```

should do the trick for you.

the last line will print the endpoint response to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information:

- [Groovy HTTP Access](https://www.logicmonitor.com/support/terminology-syntax/scripting-support/access-a-website-from-groovy/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: It's working well for GET request, But facing issue with POST request.
Any suggestion for passing the POST request ?

Comment: It's working well for GET request, But facing issue with POST request.
Any suggestion for passing the POST request ?
Method : POST
Payload/Request : {"data": { "Environment": "CI", "Host": "abc.com" }}
Headers: Content-Type: application/json
Endpoint/URL : https://example.com